# R - connecting to remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to connect in R to remote mysql server, but without success.

That is my code -

```
library(RMySQL)
drv = dbDriver("MySQL")
mydb = dbConnect(drv,host="*.*.*.*",dbname="dbname",user="user",pass="pass")
```

but I get the following error -

> Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user
>   'user'@'ec2-*-*-*-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com'

It is trying to connect to local host, and not the host I specified in the code.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you haven't granted proper access for this user where queries are coming from ec2----.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

Try something like:

CREATE USER 'user'@'ec2----.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'user'@'ec2----.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com';